# How to make a div fixed on sidebar and don't overlap

Tags: css

I have 2 div like

```
<div class="container">
example data example data example data ...
</div>

<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

and i style that like

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.sidebar {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:60px;
}
```

I want my sidebar has fixed and when i scale small width window that don't overlap

How to do that thanks 
here is my example **http://jsfiddle.net/npUaf/**

Comment: If you don't want it to overlap, then what should it do? It has to go somewhere.

Comment: the sidebar should be only that square or a bar?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I think that div can disappear ...

Comment: @BrianGlaz True Story :DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment "I think that div can disappear" you can use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/npUaf/7/)

Comment: thank so much but is posible? if that has horizontal scrolling insted of disappear?

Comment: No, you can't have it all. When you use `position:fixed` it will overflow, since it's positioned outside the flow. So you have two options: 1) make it dissapear; 2) let it overflow;

Comment: in real i have container width:1000px;, and sidebar div with other width, how make max-width auto caculator? (i think in other monitor has other Resolution it will fail ?) thank

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin-right: 200px;
    float: right;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:blue;
    }
```

Use this css for container.